# Libreoffice calc: make search default to 'value' not 'formula'

Tags: libreoffice, search

When searching in LibreOffice Calc, the default 'search in' choice is 'Formulas'.  This is annoying to me because 99% of my searching is for values.  (OpenOffice either defaulted to values, or I changed it so long ago that I don't remember how I did it).

So instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and type the search item, it's

> Click "Find and Replace"
>
> Click "Other Options"
>
> Click "Values"

...every...stinkin'....time

Is there a way to make 'Values' the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to make searching on values the default.

A feature request was opened here to get this capability: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102615 but it has been open for over four years as of this writing.